# Hide div before reaching footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the follow HTML and js code snippets make using the UIKIT css framework,
I'm trying to hide left side sticky div on reaching the parallax div container.
 [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Kajol2608/pen/MPLKoq?editors=1000)

I tried to the following js code for this purpose but I've been unable to  do so.

```js
document.onscroll = function() {
    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY > document.body.clientHeight) {
        document.getElementById('side-content').style.display='none';
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.20/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.20/js/uikit.min.js"></script>

<div class="uk-container">
  <div class="uk-text-center" uk-grid>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4">
      <div class="uk-panel uk-text-center" id="side-content" style="z-index: 980;" uk-sticky="bottom: #offset">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">
            <h3 class="uk-card-title">Primary</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-3-4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque ipsam at unde placeat et nulla maxime maiores, repudiandae, perspiciatis ipsum ea error tenetur temporibus voluptatibus illo atque eaque eius autem aliquam! Saepe ipsam corrupti culpa
        earum placeat, aliquam esse ad ducimus harum beatae facere delectus minima minus perspiciatis totam laboriosam sint quaerat reprehenderit illum hic quam et eius. Veritatis praesentium officia modi, alias quos, iste voluptate quisquam quasi, labore
        sunt consectetur at inventore consequatur esse recusandae ipsam veniam dignissimos. Id explicabo nihil magnam vel dolorum cumque minus recusandae officiis illo architecto, dolor voluptates placeat aut ex quasi quos aliquid qui quisquam odit, nisi.
        Asperiores eveniet recusandae, natus ipsum placeat similique ad. Dolorum quia, hic optio odio illo ut sit quibusdam distinctio maxime fugiat.</p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad tempora quia similique, error iusto repudiandae explicabo neque doloribus eos dolorum eum perspiciatis. Maxime vero dolore facilis perferendis aspernatur fuga sit, quisquam a vel sunt impedit minus eos consequatur maiores quibusdam repellat qui! Praesentium labore enim eveniet dolores soluta! Accusamus recusandae sequi neque fugit, error corporis! Similique error, maiores quae facere voluptas reprehenderit excepturi eaque, eveniet ea quas odit labore? Eius aliquid ab tenetur nemo debitis nulla expedita inventore totam eos. Ullam totam eligendi inventore dolorem praesentium explicabo unde architecto laboriosam qui voluptate. Hic cum dicta dolor non aperiam, voluptatem, error deserunt velit eligendi tempora eos! Recusandae, tempore! Pariatur laudantium eaque molestiae soluta dolore nam porro, alias, quis similique accusantium accusamus voluptas dicta, cupiditate blanditiis. Quisquam doloribus voluptates, reiciendis excepturi animi saepe autem fugiat impedit rem eius deserunt dolorem porro architecto fuga officia sint explicabo, similique quam omnis molestias dolore quibusdam temporibus incidunt iure! Illo, distinctio blanditiis. Debitis animi qui dignissimos deserunt a ab dicta adipisci veniam quas, explicabo voluptatem possimus asperiores. Nihil vero rerum sapiente incidunt, libero laudantium nisi numquam, ullam dolore optio unde molestias error labore est! Nemo, repudiandae maxime aperiam vel sed itaque voluptatum. A nobis obcaecati, accusamus ad aliquid nulla harum? Nobis consequuntur reprehenderit accusantium illum et suscipit officia ipsam saepe, adipisci laboriosam fugit cumque dolorem fuga vitae est quisquam amet tenetur facilis vel eius. Doloribus est officia aperiam. Modi sed voluptates ullam accusantium accusamus quas velit, cum aspernatur at quia illo? Tempore corporis maxime eligendi ullam sapiente temporibus, excepturi incidunt ipsam. Velit necessitatibus optio saepe dicta fugit deserunt in fuga, nesciunt, accusamus repellat, eos voluptatem? Deserunt necessitatibus iste autem, eos quas explicabo voluptas facilis blanditiis est! Quasi veniam ut ab minima voluptatibus vitae sint maxime at? Nemo animi ab enim nisi eveniet, distinctio minus saepe iure a amet quod laudantium architecto laboriosam vero eum tempora fugit aut doloribus quisquam quaerat accusamus facilis minima officiis culpa! Nesciunt pariatur sequi hic, debitis enim harum molestias reiciendis eaque mollitia laboriosam ipsa officiis voluptates, labore asperiores blanditiis ducimus, autem quasi sunt. Impedit, temporibus molestiae obcaecati minima vel cumque accusantium blanditiis eligendi rem explicabo qui corporis quia! Possimus dolorum quaerat asperiores ad eaque odit labore ipsam, numquam voluptate accusamus, vitae praesentium alias autem delectus eius natus earum adipisci assumenda aliquid. Velit similique deleniti facere suscipit odio commodi quidem, nesciunt dignissimos quam odit quos dolorum sequi esse, mollitia est, culpa magni rem dicta. Quos nostrum odit adipisci facere recusandae alias ea quia voluptates soluta quibusdam modi placeat animi minus doloribus quam provident unde explicabo, officia dolores architecto praesentium obcaecati. Mollitia est cum nulla quo? Ullam atque fugiat unde porro, corrupti mollitia iste. Eos inventore ad consectetur, maiores dolore ipsum non! Officiis atque ea accusantium ex tempora delectus explicabo eaque amet, deserunt nobis velit, harum dolor. Vitae, alias assumenda? Aliquam mollitia eos, dolorem alias ut deserunt temporibus, et quas est hic excepturi repellendus blanditiis quo? Corporis aspernatur laboriosam sequi? Non doloribus natus dolor tempora, tempore eaque illum quas veritatis accusantium unde laboriosam deserunt.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="uk-height-large uk-background-cover uk-light uk-flex" uk-parallax="bgy: -200" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/1200x550/?nature');">

    <h1 class="uk-width-1-2@m uk-text-center uk-margin-auto uk-margin-auto-vertical">Headline</h1>

</div>
<footer class="uk-background-primary">
  <div class="container" uk-grid>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4">
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="uk-width-1-4">
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="uk-width-1-4">
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="uk-width-1-4">
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I would be very helpful if anyone could suggest how can hide the div.

Comment: this code works, check: https://jsfiddle.net/swr0uvjf/ Did you attach the JS to the HTML properly?

Comment: @rufus1530 you fiddle does not hide the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) on your parallax element.

> The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an
>   element and its position relative to the viewport.

It returns an object with different properties, where one is "top". Simply subtract `top` by the `window.innerHeight` and if it's <= 0 then it has appeared in the view port.

```js
let sideC = document.getElementById("side-content");
let paral = document.getElementById("parallax");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if(paral.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight <= 0){
    $(sideC).fadeOut(1000);
  } else {
    $(sideC).fadeIn(1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.20/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.20/js/uikit.min.js"></script>

<div class="uk-container">
  <div class="uk-text-center" uk-grid>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4">
      <div class="uk-panel uk-text-center" id="side-content" style="z-index: 980;" uk-sticky="bottom: #offset">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">
          <h3 class="uk-card-title">Primary</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-3-4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque ipsam at unde placeat et nulla maxime maiores, repudiandae, perspiciatis ipsum ea error tenetur temporibus voluptatibus illo atque eaque eius autem aliquam! Saepe ipsam corrupti culpa
        earum placeat, aliquam esse ad ducimus harum beatae facere delectus minima minus perspiciatis totam laboriosam sint quaerat reprehenderit illum hic quam et eius. Veritatis praesentium officia modi, alias quos, iste voluptate quisquam quasi, labore
        sunt consectetur at inventore consequatur esse recusandae ipsam veniam dignissimos. Id explicabo nihil magnam vel dolorum cumque minus recusandae officiis illo architecto, dolor voluptates placeat aut ex quasi quos aliquid qui quisquam odit, nisi.
        Asperiores eveniet recusandae, natus ipsum placeat similique ad. Dolorum quia, hic optio odio illo ut sit quibusdam distinctio maxime fugiat.</p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad tempora quia similique, error iusto repudiandae explicabo neque doloribus eos dolorum eum perspiciatis. Maxime vero dolore facilis perferendis aspernatur fuga sit, quisquam a vel sunt impedit
      minus eos consequatur maiores quibusdam repellat qui! Praesentium labore enim eveniet dolores soluta! Accusamus recusandae sequi neque fugit, error corporis! Similique error, maiores quae facere voluptas reprehenderit excepturi eaque, eveniet ea
      quas odit labore? Eius aliquid ab tenetur nemo debitis nulla expedita inventore totam eos. Ullam totam eligendi inventore dolorem praesentium explicabo unde architecto laboriosam qui voluptate. Hic cum dicta dolor non aperiam, voluptatem, error
      deserunt velit eligendi tempora eos! Recusandae, tempore! Pariatur laudantium eaque molestiae soluta dolore nam porro, alias, quis similique accusantium accusamus voluptas dicta, cupiditate blanditiis. Quisquam doloribus voluptates, reiciendis excepturi
      animi saepe autem fugiat impedit rem eius deserunt dolorem porro architecto fuga officia sint explicabo, similique quam omnis molestias dolore quibusdam temporibus incidunt iure! Illo, distinctio blanditiis. Debitis animi qui dignissimos deserunt
      a ab dicta adipisci veniam quas, explicabo voluptatem possimus asperiores. Nihil vero rerum sapiente incidunt, libero laudantium nisi numquam, ullam dolore optio unde molestias error labore est! Nemo, repudiandae maxime aperiam vel sed itaque voluptatum.
      A nobis obcaecati, accusamus ad aliquid nulla harum? Nobis consequuntur reprehenderit accusantium illum et suscipit officia ipsam saepe, adipisci laboriosam fugit cumque dolorem fuga vitae est quisquam amet tenetur facilis vel eius. Doloribus est
      officia aperiam. Modi sed voluptates ullam accusantium accusamus quas velit, cum aspernatur at quia illo? Tempore corporis maxime eligendi ullam sapiente temporibus, excepturi incidunt ipsam. Velit necessitatibus optio saepe dicta fugit deserunt
      in fuga, nesciunt, accusamus repellat, eos voluptatem? Deserunt necessitatibus iste autem, eos quas explicabo voluptas facilis blanditiis est! Quasi veniam ut ab minima voluptatibus vitae sint maxime at? Nemo animi ab enim nisi eveniet, distinctio
      minus saepe iure a amet quod laudantium architecto laboriosam vero eum tempora fugit aut doloribus quisquam quaerat accusamus facilis minima officiis culpa! Nesciunt pariatur sequi hic, debitis enim harum molestias reiciendis eaque mollitia laboriosam
      ipsa officiis voluptates, labore asperiores blanditiis ducimus, autem quasi sunt. Impedit, temporibus molestiae obcaecati minima vel cumque accusantium blanditiis eligendi rem explicabo qui corporis quia! Possimus dolorum quaerat asperiores ad eaque
      odit labore ipsam, numquam voluptate accusamus, vitae praesentium alias autem delectus eius natus earum adipisci assumenda aliquid. Velit similique deleniti facere suscipit odio commodi quidem, nesciunt dignissimos quam odit quos dolorum sequi esse,
      mollitia est, culpa magni rem dicta. Quos nostrum odit adipisci facere recusandae alias ea quia voluptates soluta quibusdam modi placeat animi minus doloribus quam provident unde explicabo, officia dolores architecto praesentium obcaecati. Mollitia
      est cum nulla quo? Ullam atque fugiat unde porro, corrupti mollitia iste. Eos inventore ad consectetur, maiores dolore ipsum non! Officiis atque ea accusantium ex tempora delectus explicabo eaque amet, deserunt nobis velit, harum dolor. Vitae, alias
      assumenda? Aliquam mollitia eos, dolorem alias ut deserunt temporibus, et quas est hic excepturi repellendus blanditiis quo? Corporis aspernatur laboriosam sequi? Non doloribus natus dolor tempora, tempore eaque illum quas veritatis accusantium
      unde laboriosam deserunt.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parallax" class="uk-height-large uk-background-cover uk-light uk-flex" uk-parallax="bgy: -200" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/1200x550/?nature');">

  <h1 class="uk-width-1-2@m uk-text-center uk-margin-auto uk-margin-auto-vertical">Headline</h1>

</div>
<footer class="uk-background-primary">
  <div class="container" uk-grid>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4">
      <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4">
      <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4">
      <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4">
      <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Your code works in the above snippet but I got js error **paral.getBoundingClientRect is not a function**

Comment: @kajol that's because you need to add the id "parallax" to your HTML element (check html above to see where I put it). You also should wrap the code in a `window.addEventListener("load", function(){ /** code here **/});`, if that still doesn't work. let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this function will get you the exact element position so you can adjust your code accordingly.

```
document.onscroll = function() {    
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName("uk-height-large");        
    var divOffset = offset(div[0]); 

    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY > divOffset.top + 250) {
        document.getElementById('side-content').style.display='none';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('side-content').style.display='block';
    }
}    

function offset(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    return { top: rect.top + scrollTop, left: rect.left + scrollLeft }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You was almost there, the problem is that you need to take into account that document.body.clientHeight is the bottom of the page and what you are looking for is the element with the class "uk-background-primary" that corresponds to your footer.

Here it is the snippet:

```js
document.onscroll = function() {
   
    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY > document.body.getElementsByClassName("uk-background-primary")[0].offsetTop) {
       document.getElementById('side-content').style.display='none';
    }
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.20/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.20/js/uikit.min.js"></script>

    <div class="uk-container">
      <div class="uk-text-center" uk-grid>
        <div class="uk-width-1-4">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-text-center" id="side-content" style="z-index: 980;" uk-sticky="bottom: #offset">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">
                <h3 class="uk-card-title">Primary</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-3-4">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque ipsam at unde placeat et nulla maxime maiores, repudiandae, perspiciatis ipsum ea error tenetur temporibus voluptatibus illo atque eaque eius autem aliquam! Saepe ipsam corrupti culpa
            earum placeat, aliquam esse ad ducimus harum beatae facere delectus minima minus perspiciatis totam laboriosam sint quaerat reprehenderit illum hic quam et eius. Veritatis praesentium officia modi, alias quos, iste voluptate quisquam quasi, labore
            sunt consectetur at inventore consequatur esse recusandae ipsam veniam dignissimos. Id explicabo nihil magnam vel dolorum cumque minus recusandae officiis illo architecto, dolor voluptates placeat aut ex quasi quos aliquid qui quisquam odit, nisi.
            Asperiores eveniet recusandae, natus ipsum placeat similique ad. Dolorum quia, hic optio odio illo ut sit quibusdam distinctio maxime fugiat.</p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad tempora quia similique, error iusto repudiandae explicabo neque doloribus eos dolorum eum perspiciatis. Maxime vero dolore facilis perferendis aspernatur fuga sit, quisquam a vel sunt impedit minus eos consequatur maiores quibusdam repellat qui! Praesentium labore enim eveniet dolores soluta! Accusamus recusandae sequi neque fugit, error corporis! Similique error, maiores quae facere voluptas reprehenderit excepturi eaque, eveniet ea quas odit labore? Eius aliquid ab tenetur nemo debitis nulla expedita inventore totam eos. Ullam totam eligendi inventore dolorem praesentium explicabo unde architecto laboriosam qui voluptate. Hic cum dicta dolor non aperiam, voluptatem, error deserunt velit eligendi tempora eos! Recusandae, tempore! Pariatur laudantium eaque molestiae soluta dolore nam porro, alias, quis similique accusantium accusamus voluptas dicta, cupiditate blanditiis. Quisquam doloribus voluptates, reiciendis excepturi animi saepe autem fugiat impedit rem eius deserunt dolorem porro architecto fuga officia sint explicabo, similique quam omnis molestias dolore quibusdam temporibus incidunt iure! Illo, distinctio blanditiis. Debitis animi qui dignissimos deserunt a ab dicta adipisci veniam quas, explicabo voluptatem possimus asperiores. Nihil vero rerum sapiente incidunt, libero laudantium nisi numquam, ullam dolore optio unde molestias error labore est! Nemo, repudiandae maxime aperiam vel sed itaque voluptatum. A nobis obcaecati, accusamus ad aliquid nulla harum? Nobis consequuntur reprehenderit accusantium illum et suscipit officia ipsam saepe, adipisci laboriosam fugit cumque dolorem fuga vitae est quisquam amet tenetur facilis vel eius. Doloribus est officia aperiam. Modi sed voluptates ullam accusantium accusamus quas velit, cum aspernatur at quia illo? Tempore corporis maxime eligendi ullam sapiente temporibus, excepturi incidunt ipsam. Velit necessitatibus optio saepe dicta fugit deserunt in fuga, nesciunt, accusamus repellat, eos voluptatem? Deserunt necessitatibus iste autem, eos quas explicabo voluptas facilis blanditiis est! Quasi veniam ut ab minima voluptatibus vitae sint maxime at? Nemo animi ab enim nisi eveniet, distinctio minus saepe iure a amet quod laudantium architecto laboriosam vero eum tempora fugit aut doloribus quisquam quaerat accusamus facilis minima officiis culpa! Nesciunt pariatur sequi hic, debitis enim harum molestias reiciendis eaque mollitia laboriosam ipsa officiis voluptates, labore asperiores blanditiis ducimus, autem quasi sunt. Impedit, temporibus molestiae obcaecati minima vel cumque accusantium blanditiis eligendi rem explicabo qui corporis quia! Possimus dolorum quaerat asperiores ad eaque odit labore ipsam, numquam voluptate accusamus, vitae praesentium alias autem delectus eius natus earum adipisci assumenda aliquid. Velit similique deleniti facere suscipit odio commodi quidem, nesciunt dignissimos quam odit quos dolorum sequi esse, mollitia est, culpa magni rem dicta. Quos nostrum odit adipisci facere recusandae alias ea quia voluptates soluta quibusdam modi placeat animi minus doloribus quam provident unde explicabo, officia dolores architecto praesentium obcaecati. Mollitia est cum nulla quo? Ullam atque fugiat unde porro, corrupti mollitia iste. Eos inventore ad consectetur, maiores dolore ipsum non! Officiis atque ea accusantium ex tempora delectus explicabo eaque amet, deserunt nobis velit, harum dolor. Vitae, alias assumenda? Aliquam mollitia eos, dolorem alias ut deserunt temporibus, et quas est hic excepturi repellendus blanditiis quo? Corporis aspernatur laboriosam sequi? Non doloribus natus dolor tempora, tempore eaque illum quas veritatis accusantium unde laboriosam deserunt.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-height-large uk-background-cover uk-light uk-flex" uk-parallax="bgy: -200" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/1200x550/?nature');">

        <h1 class="uk-width-1-2@m uk-text-center uk-margin-auto uk-margin-auto-vertical">Headline</h1>

    </div>
    <footer class="uk-background-primary">
      <div class="container" uk-grid>
        <div class="uk-width-1-4">
        <ul>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item1</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="uk-width-1-4">
        <ul>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item1</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="uk-width-1-4">
        <ul>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item1</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="uk-width-1-4">
        <ul>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item1</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```